# How do I retrieve failed journal entries when syncing from IDS to QBD?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I am creating two Journals in IDS using JournalEntry POST, out of which only one journal is syncing and appearing in QBD.

I tried to retrieve the failed journal by querying for ErroredObjectsOnly="true", but got an error - Attribute 'ErroredObjectsOnly' is not allowed to appear in element 'JournalEntryQuery'

I tried setting ObjectStateEnable to true in the query, but the result contains only journals that have been successfully synced.

Retrieve all only returns journals that are successful.

Is there any way by which I can retrieve the failed journal entries?

Comment: Post the complete XML request you are making using ErroredObjectsOnly.

Comment: Request body - 

<JournalEntryQuery ErroredObjectsOnly="true" xmlns='http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2'>
</JournalEntryQuery>

Comment: Response body - 

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<RestResponse xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
    <Error RequestId="75206f21ce35415b9686589609479cda">
        <RequestName>ErrorRequest</RequestName>
        <ProcessedTime>2013-04-30T11:23:54.360Z</ProcessedTime>
        <ErrorCode>-2001</ErrorCode>
        <ErrorDesc>cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'ErroredObjectsOnly' is not allowed to appear in element 'JournalEntryQuery'.</ErrorDesc>
    </Error>
</RestResponse>

Comment: Try calling SyncStatus on the JournalEntry object: http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/SyncStatus

Comment: Thanks. This looks like a bug in IDS in that it doesn't recognize the ErroredObjectsOnly attribute. I have submitted a bug ticket for it.

Comment: Just wanted to check if you received any updates on the bug? Can you please share the bug number/id?